# Cocos2D CCSprite fake depth?

Tags: 3d, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, depth

I am currently doing a flip card effect in Cocos2D. What I am currently trying to achieve is the perception of depth in my CCSprite. Now I am not looking for some all out 3D code/program or to use Cocos3D.

All I want is to do is to make the illusion that the CCSprite that is spinning to have a little bit of depth to provide more realism in my game.

Now the sprite is not spinning that fast, it is at a moderate pace and thats why I am trying to achieve this.

Does anyone know how I can go upon this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check code of CCTransitionFlipX and CCTransitionFlipY in cocos2d sources. They use CCOrbitCamera actions. Maybe it will be helpful to you.

Comment: That will just turn a sprite which I don't need to do (I already did it in fact). I need a way to fake depth. Not width or length

Comment: you can try to create your own action that will combine orbit, scale and move action and try achieve needed effect. or just run these actions on your node/sprite/etc.

Comment: I know, I'm just looking for a specific API or function that will do this so I can get to this point of creating my own action.

Comment: Also I must note that I am using CCSpriteBatchNode so I can't do anything regarding cameras.